# Creating and updating documents synchronously with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm wondering what the best approach would be to realize the following situation in Node.js and mongoose:

I'm having a collection with users and a collection with groups. I want users to be able to create new groups and add people to them (very similar to people creating a new whatsapp group). I use the following schemas for the user and group documents:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    email: String, 
    hashed_password: String,
    salt: String,
    name: String,
    groups: [{
        _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'groups' }, 
        name: String
    }]
});

var groupSchema= mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: String,
    creator: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    users: [{
        _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'users' }, 
        rankInGroup: { type: Number, required: true }
    }]
});
```

At this moment I have a function that takes the following arguments: the email address (*groupCreator*) of the user who is creating the group, the name of the new group (*newGroupName*), and the userids of the users (*newGroupMembers*) that need to be added to the group. This function first finds the users that need to be added to the group (using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8304213/1502438)) and then adds the user ids of these users to the users array in the group document like this:

```
function(groupCreator, newGroupName, newGroupMembers , callback) {
    userModel.findOne({
        email: emailGroupCreator
    }, function(err,creator){
        //load document of user who creates the group into creator variable
        var newGroup = new groupModel({ 
            name: newGroupName, 
            creator: creator._id, 
            users: [{_id: creator._id, rank: 0}] //add group creator to the group
            });

        userModel.find({
            email: { $in: newGroupMembers }
        }, function(err,users){                         
            //for now assume no error occurred fetching users
            users.forEach(function(user) {                              
                newGroup.users.push({_id: user._id, rank: 0}); //add user to group
                user.groups.push({_id:newGroup._id,name:newGroup.name}); //add group to user
            }
            newGroup.save(function (err) {
            //for now assume no error occurred
            creator.groups.push({_id: newGroup._id, name: newGroup.name}); //add group to creator
            creator.save(function (err) {
                //for now assume no error occurred

                /* save/update the user documents here by doing something like
                newMembers.forEach(function(newMember) {
                    newMember.save(function (err) {
                        if(err){
                            callback(500, {success: false, response: "Group created but failure while adding group to user: "+newMember.email});
                        }
                    });
                });
                callback(200, {success: true, response: "Group created successfully!"});
                */ 
            });
        }
    });
}
```

So I want this function to:

- Find the user document of the group creator based on its email address stored in groupCreator
- Create a new group (newGroup) and add the creator to its users array
- Find all the users that need to be added to the group
- Update the groups array in all the user documents with the groupid (newGroup._id) of the newly created group
- Make a callback if all this is successfully executed

The problem here is that the updating of all the user documents of the users added to the group happens asynchronously, but I want to be sure that all the user documents are updated correctly before I return a success or failure callback. How can I update all the user documents before I continue with the rest of the code (maybe not using a foreach)? Is my initial approach of retrieving all the user documents good or are there better ways to do this?

So the bottom line question is; how can I save multiple user documents and continue with the rest of the code (send a callback to notify success or failure) after all the save actions are performed, or is there a way to save all the documents at once?

NB The reason why I want (some) of the same information in both the user and the group document is because I don't want to load all the group info for a user if he logs in, only the basic group information. See also [this source](http://seanhess.github.io/2012/02/01/mongodb_relational.html) under the section many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Basics here is that JavaScript `.forEach()` cannot respect async callbacks. But it is basically unclear in your question where your data ( variables referenced that are not defined in the listed code ) is coming from or the full intent of your update. You can make these points clearer by including the other relevant actions in your question and explaining an expected result from a source data sample.

Comment: I've added some more information and a list of what this function should do :)

Comment: You can use an async iterator like [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Hmm that looks interesting, I just stumbled upon this page (http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice) referring to async.parallel. Will look into that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk) pointed me in the right direction; [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) make it possible to iterate over the documents and update them one at a time. After that the rest of the code gets executed. This is how my code looks now:

```
async.each(groupMembersDocs, function (newMember, loopCallback) {
    //console.log('Processing user ' + newMember.email + '\n');
    userModel.update({
        email: newMember.email
    }, {
        $push: { 'groups' : {_id: newGroup._id, name: newGroup.name} }
    }, function (err, data) { 
        if(err){
            console.log("error: "+err);
            loopCallback('Failure.. :'+err);
        } else{
            newGroup.users.push({_id: newMember._id, rank: -1});
            loopCallback();
        }
    });
}, function (err){
    if(err){
        console.log("error: "+err);
        callback(500, {success: false, response: "Error while adding users to group"});
    } else{
        newGroup.save(function (err) {
            callback(201, {success: true, response: "Group created successfully"});
        });
    }
})
```