# How do I update more than one mongodb records at once?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I am creating a basic todo app using express and mongodb at the backend, I have a task schema that looks like this :

```
var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    task: String,
    time:Date,
    done:Boolean,
    id:Number   
});
```

By default the done is not set, but in the frontend I have a unordered list and bunch of lines and each line has a checkbox next to it , I want that when the user selects a list of tasks from checkboxes and click on done button it should go as a post request and mongodb should update all tasks at once , is it possible? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Did you try `findAndModify` (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) ?

Comment: Or maybe you can use $in to find documents matching the multiple ids (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array?answertab=votes#tab-top) then modify the each document

Comment: yeah it was helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the data in the db:

```
[
 {
   _id: "1",
   task: 'hello1',
   time: '11-02-2015',
   done: false
 },
 {
   _id: "2",
   task: 'hello2',
   time: '11-02-2015',
   done: false
 },
 {
   _id: "3",
   task: 'hello3',
   time: '11-02-2015',
   done: false
 },
 {
   _id: "4",
   task: 'hello4',
   time: '11-02-2015',
   done: false
 },
 {
   _id: "5",
   task: 'hello5',
   time: '11-02-2015',
   done: false
 }
];
```

So you will be sending all selected tasks (let's call it an array) via `POST` request on when `Done` is clicked.

Array will be contain list of taskIds like this:

```
var tasksArr = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4"
];
```

So you will be doing something like this in your route function..

```
var bulk = TaskSchema.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

for (var taskId in tasksArr) {
   bulk.find({_id: taskId}).update({
     '$set': {done: true}
   });
}

bulk.execute(function(err, bulkres) {
   console.log('modified:', bulkres.nModified);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,