# Q.all then not waiting for promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, q

UPDATE - Solution:
I was for looping instead should have used MongoDBs `$in` feature - [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array)

I have the following Q.all block:

```
Q.all([
   getFirstBlock(),
   getSecondBlock(),
])
.then(function(){
   getSecondBlockProcessed();
})
.then(function(){
   res.json(completeArray);
});
```

The problem I have is when I go into the final `then` block I notice that the function `getSecondBlockProcessed` has not been completed.
Everything in the first `Q.all` is done. 
Why isn't that promise getting resolved?

And the method in question looks like:

```
var getSecondBlockProcessed = function() {
    return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      for (var i=0; i<mostInRegion.length; i++){
        Person.find(
          {_id: mostInRegion[i]['_id']},
          {question:1, country: 1},
          function(err, found) {
            mostInRegion2.push(found);
          })
      }
      resolve();
      });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated/what have i overlooked?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to **`return`** `getSecondBlockProcessed();` if it is asynchronous and returns a promise! Or just do `.then(getSecondBlockProcessed)`

Comment: You mean like: `.then(function(){
        return getSecondBlockProcessed();
      })`

Comment: @Bergi Tried that - didnt work.
Could it be do to with teh fact i have a `find()` in  for loop?
p.s. I dont think this a duplicate question as mine has a different.

Comment: @Bergi so the issue is when the `resolve()` is placed after the for loop (where i want it to be) it doesnt return the promise.
If i place within the loop it only gives me one result (after the first loop in).

Comment: @Bergi solved it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array.
Please remove duplicate question as I'm updating my question

Comment: Oh, right, that's another issue. You should promisify `find`, and use `Promise.all` or `Promise.map` to wait for the results of the loop. I did reopen so that you can post your solution as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)