# Mongoose: Delete all referenced objects in an array when deleting referencing object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

In my MEAN-application (Angular2) I want to delete all referenced objects when deleting the object itself. I'm using Mongoose with the remove middleware. So my question.js file looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Answer = require('../models/answer');

var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    questionTxt: {type: String, required: true},
    position: {type: Number, min: 0, required: true},
    answers: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Answer"}],
    followUpQuestions: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Question"}],
    additionalInfoText: {type: String},
    lastChangedBy: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    lastChanged: {type: Date},
    isRoot: {type: Boolean}
});

/**********************************************
 *  Deletes all answers and questions referenced by this question
 ***********************************************/

schema.post('remove', function(doc) {
    var deletedQuestion = doc;
        //code missing to find the answers and delete all referenced answers
    });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

I know I can find one by using:

```
Answer.findById(doc.answer, function(err, doc){});
```

I also now that I can use the find method to find more than one element and adding a query. But I just found stuff to find one specific id or to only delete them from the array. But I want the objects to be removed and not just the reference in that array.

If it's duplicated, feel free to close this question, but I didn't found the answer after googling, stack overflowing and in the related topics.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb/mongoose findMany - find all documents with IDs listed in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array). This I'd indeed a duplicate. The above should get you where you need to go.

Comment: @Brudus: Any update on middleware usage. Did it worked for you ?

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you simply add your own `'remove'` Mongoose [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) on the `Question` schema to remove all other documents i.e. answers that references the question.

Example: In middleware function, you can do something like this:

```
QuestionSchema.pre('remove', function(callback) {
    // Remove all the docs that refers
    this.model('Answers').remove({ Question_Id: this._id }, callback);
});
```

---

If you are interested to use a cascading delete, you can look into a npm module built for it. 
Cascading-Relations - Links [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cascading-relations) & [Git](https://github.com/jraede/cascading-relations)

> $cascadeDelete defines whether or not deleting a document will also delete its related documents. If this is set to true, then all related documents will be deleted when the main document is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to figure out how to delete a bunch of documents at once in an array, and realized from your post: *duh*, make an instance method and then for loop and call it! Boom! A success! Thank you!