# Mongoose find with multiple values for a field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
Select * from table_name where sport_type LIKE ('Cricket','Football');
```

I am trying to find the documents with `sport_type`of Cricket and Football using `find`

```
table.find({ sport_type : "Cricket" })
```

Can anyone help me to do so

Comment: Is there a reason in your SQL example that you're using `LIKE` instead of `IN`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb/mongoose findMany - find all documents with IDs listed in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `$or`:

```
table.find( { $or:[ {'sport_type':'Cricket'}, {'sport_type':'Football'} ]}, 
  function(err,docs){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: the equivalent of your answer is `Select * from table_name where sport_type =  'Cricket' or sport_type =  'Football';`. He looks for a `LIKE` comparison.

Comment: @Mitchapp the OP is trying to find documents with `sport_type` of `Cricket` or `Football`. I don't think he is looking for a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's too late to answer but hopefully it will help other people.

You can use `$in` operator, like this:

```
mongoose.find({sport_type: {$in: ['Cricket', 'Football']}})
```

You provide an array to `$in` operator and it will return all the documents which have an exact sport_type in the array specified.