# Evaluating an Array of MongoDB IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a search feature where filtered data is returned from my mongoDB based on a user's input for various filters. Here's an example, where records are returned that match for `lastName` values. This array of values is passed in to Mongoose/Mongo using `$in`:

```
if (lastName) {
    let arrlastName = [];
    arrlastName = lastName.split(",");
    _.each(arrlastName, (l, key, c) => {
        arrlastName[key] = new RegExp(arrlastName[key], "i");
    });
    search['name.last'] = { $in: arrlastName };
}
```

The above code works as expected.

However, in addition to matching for names, I want to return records based on a filter that evaluates a user's "_id". The challenge is, "_id" here is not a string, but a mongoDB object Id.

Now, this is easy enough to do when I'm searching for a single value for "_id", in which case I would just do this:

```
  if (personId) search['_id'] = new mongo.ObjectID(personId);
```

That also works as expected. This will return just the results that match this one `_id`.

But how do I evaluate against an array of values in this situation - like I'm doing for `lastName` in the code near the top of this question? What would that look like? This is what I tried (that did not work):

```
  if (person) {
    let personId = new mongo.ObjectID(person);
    let arrPerson = [];
    arrPerson = personId.split(",");
    _.each(arrPerson, (l, key, c) => {
    arrPerson[key] = new RegExp(arrPerson[key], "i");
    });
    search['_id'] = { $in: arrPerson };
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag & the intro to your question mention mongoose, but all of your logic seems to be using mongo directly.

If you are using mongoose [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array) should solve your question.

Otherwise, this logic from the MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) may be helpful

```
db.bios.find(
  {
    _id: { $in: [ 5,  ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0013") ] }
  }
)
```