# how to find array of objects and return the corresponding object array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

In the above code we pass the `id` and find the corresponding user object. How do we pass an array of `ids[]` and get the corresponding array of `user[]` objects?

Comment: I think you are using mongoose orm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array it may answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You can juste use the `$in` operator :

```
User.find({
    _id: {$in: your_array_of_ids}
}).toArray(function(err, users) {
    // users is your user's array
});
```