# find user details from array of object ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have an array of object ids which i extracted from another instance.
these object ids represent user ids in user model. i would like to use these object ids to get the user details

How i got object ids

```
        const chatrooms = await ChatRoom.find({owners:{$all:[user._id]}}) 
        const allowners = chatrooms.flatMap(room => room.owners) 
        const vendors = allowners.filter(item => !item.equals(userid))
```

object ids

```
 vendors = [
           "5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b",
           "5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8",.....
           ]
```

user schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    require: true,
    trim:true
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

i have tried a for loop which is not working

```
   const vendorDetails = []
    for(let i=0; i<=vendors.length; i++)
        {
            vendorDetails[i] = User.find({_id:vendors[i]}) 
        }
        console.log(vendorDetails)
```

Result i am expecting is something like this

```
   vendorDetails = [ { _id: 5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b,
                    name: 'vithu'
                    },
                    {
                      _id: 5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8,
                    name: 'vcs'
                    }....]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb/mongoose findMany - find all documents with IDs listed in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array)

Comment: i tried
const vendorDetails = []
        vendorDetails = User.find( { _id : { $in : vendors } } ) 
           
        res.send(vendorDetails)
result:
{}

Comment: You need to use the actual code of the duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
  db.collection.find( { _id : { $in : yourArrayOfIds } } );
```

Comment: i tried this:
const vendors = allowners.filter(item => !item.equals(userid));
        
        
        const vendorDetails = [];
        vendorDetails = User.find( { _id : { $in : vendors } } ) ;
           
        res.send(vendorDetails);
result:{}

Comment: add await in query vendorDetails = await User.find( { _id : { $in : vendors } } ) ;

Comment: you need to await this and don't forget to upvote if it works for you ;) @vithushaji

Comment: still getting {} @AmirTahani

 vendorDetails = await User.find( { _id : { $in : vendors } } )

Comment: can you check if there is an actual record with this Id ? @vithushaji

Comment: try after converting array of string to array of mongoose object ids
 const vendors = vendors.map(item => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item))

Comment: const vendors = allowners.filter(item => !item.equals(userid))
console log 
[ 5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b, 5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8 ];

vendors = vendors.map(item => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item))

nothing in console after this

Comment: @AmirTahani i checked the record
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8")
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d"),
they exisit

Comment: @vithushaji try adding ObjectId to your array

Comment: @AmirTahani
 console.log(user._id) gives this result for current user . 
5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d ; 
i think adding objectid may not solve the issue

Comment: @vithushaji it's acting weird I wish I had access to see issue myself

Comment: @AmirTahani
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dnFNEGTLIri5F0wVucFAFnBZlpTJDO26

src folder
you can check routers/chat

Comment: @vithushaji you can handle it all in 1 query ChatRoom.find({owners: {$all: [user_d]}, $neq: owner.id}).populate(); something like this

Comment: what i am trying to do is finding out all chat rooms with current user and then extract the detials of other owner.
$neq: owner.id i couldnt get

Comment: @AmirTahani const chatrooms = await ChatRoom.find({owners:{$all:[user._id]}}).populate('owners','-password').exec()
worked

Comment: You are fantastic Amir :D

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to reason about your code, see below example. I hope this helps

```
async function getVendorDetails(ChatRoomModel, userObject = {}) {
    /* 
         Do your arguments verifications first (not included), then Await the result from User.find() 
         NOTE: I added "async" in front of the function in order to use "await"
         and injected the model into this function to keep it "pure", 
         you can implement this in other ways. Also pass a userObject containing
         your, well, user object :-)
    */
    const chatrooms = await ChatRoomModel.find({ owners: { $all: [userObject._id] } }); // chatrooms is expect to be an Array

    /* 
        Extract allOwners and vendor from the result {chatrooms}
        Note: I modified the variable name allowners -> allOwners
    */
    const allOwners = chatrooms.flatMap(room => room.owners); // allOwners is expected to be an Array

    /* 
        Changed the .equals() to a comparison operator
        Note: I modified the variable name in the filter function callback arg from item -> owner
    */
    const vendors = allOwners.filter(owner => owner !== userObject._id); // vendors is expected to be an Array

    try {
        // Await the result from User.find()
        const result = await User.find({
            _id: {
                $in: vendors
            }
        });
        // Return the result as a resolved promise
        return result;

    } catch (error) {
        // return error as a rejected promise
        return error;
    }
}

// Using the function

const ChatRoom = require('/path/to/model');

const user = {
    _id: '5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b'
};


// Call the function (It returns a promise)

getVendorDetails(ChatRoom, user).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```