# find elements in array available with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

exp my collection users

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('123456')
        username: 'test'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('654321')
        username: 'test2'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('789101')
        username: 'test3'
    }
]
```

my array available :

```
var usersId = [ObjectId('123456'), ObjectId('654321')]
```

i want find with field username and just in array usersId  available

my test not working :

```
db.users.find({ 
  username: keyword,
  _id: { $in: usersId  }
})
```

Comment: Please check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array

Comment: wow, thanks so much @zishe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the below code.

```
db.users.find({ 
  username: keyword,
  _id: { $in: [usersId] }
})
```