# How will I choose many objects with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have

```
[
  { name: "John" },
  { name: "Mike" },
  { name: "Homer" },
  { name: "Bart" },
  { name: "Dmitry" },
  { name: "Dan" }
]
```

How will I choose many objects with mongoose, if I use `.limit(2)` I will get `[{ name: "John" }, { name: "Mike" }]`, I need to choose `[{ name: "Bart" }, { name: "Dmitry" }]`. In default JS this method looks like `.slice(3,5)`. How will I do it with mongoose?

Comment: This type of question had been answered before. You can find the answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303900/mongodb-mongoose-findmany-find-all-documents-with-ids-listed-in-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in mongodb by using `skip(3).limit(2)`.

In Mongoose you can achieve this with `myModel.find({}, 'name', {skip: 3, limit: 2})`, you just have to insert values of `skip` and `limit` you want in third parameter of `find`.

Here's [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) with an example of skip and here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540562/13931471) to a more popular answer of similar problem.

Edit: Note that this is a short-sighted solution, you should use something else for large or changing database.

Comment: Do you think that this approach is right for finding selected values? What if there is a large data set, would you still use this approach, I mean would this be handy?

Comment: @DaniyalMalik I gave such an answer not as a scalable solution for any kind of database but just for this case, when there are few database entries and you just want to skip the first 3, `slice(3, 5)` but in mongoose. Obviously skip would be bad if database had thousands of entries or even if somebody added just one new entry. 
So to answer your question, no, on real database that changes and has a lot of values this is a bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

`Model.find({name: {$in: ["Bart", "Dmitry"]}});`